# Ignore "\n" on re.sub command python

Tags: python, string

I need to delete all the characters between `'` and `'` ignoring the command `\n`

```
string="Hello my name is 'bla bla bla\n what do you need? \n nothing!' See you bye bye."
```

I tried the following command without success:

```
 string = re.sub(r"'.*?'", "", string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

expected output:

```
"Hello my name is See you bye bye."
```

Comment: You want `re.DOTALL`, probably instead of `re.MULTILINE`. (And `\n` is a "character", not a "command".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `re.DOTALL` flag to make `.` match newline chacacters:

```
string = re.sub(r"'.*?'", "", string, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: thank you so much, I love you!